# Like returning False for no obvious reason in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a data filtering script in VBA and thought that it would be a good idea to do so using a separate function. Hence, I got the following code:

```
Sub checkFormat()
Dim cont As String
cont = "21-345"
cont = funkcja(cont)
check = cont Like "##-###"

Debug.Print check & " vartype: " & VarType(cont)

End Sub

Private Function funkcja(Param1 As String)
If ((Left(Param1, 1) = " ") Or (Right(Param1, 1) = " ")) Then
    Param1 = Trim(Param1)
    Debug.Print "Cut"
Else
    Debug.Print "Nothing to cut"
End If
Debug.Print "Returned: """ & Param1 & """" & " vartype: " & VarType(Param1)
End Function
```

The problem is that `check` variable returns False no matter whatever value I assign to it. However, once I comment out the `cont=funkcja(cont)` line, Like function begins to work as it should. Could anyone tell me what `funkcja` function does to the string so that Like returns False? I checked for variable type, but it's always set to String...

Comment: Good question. I forgot about it, but adding Dim does not change anything - Like still returns False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `funkcja` always returns "" as you did not tell it to return `Param1`:

```
Private Function funkcja(Param1 As String) as string '//type it
If ((Left(Param1, 1) = " ") Or (Right(Param1, 1) = " ")) Then
    Param1 = Trim(Param1)
    Debug.Print "Cut"
Else
    Debug.Print "Nothing to cut"
End If
'//
'//set the return value
funkcja = param1 
'//
'//
Debug.Print "Returned: """ & Param1 & """" & " vartype: " & VarType(Param1)
End Function
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.
Can a function return more than one result?

Comment: Yes, using either byref semantics, returning a type or returning a class instance.